# Can I fetch a title of an external page in my domain using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, external, fetch, title

I have several pages (all reside in the same directory as master page) that are loaded into the parent via iFrame.  I would like to fetch each one of the child pages titles and load them into an array.  Is that possible?

Best I could do so far is to pass the tile from a child page when the page is loaded into an iFrame, but I need to preload all the titles from the start in order to populate the table of contents as shown below:

**Parent code:**

```
var pages = new Array("page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html");
var maxPages = pages.length;

function pageTitle(title){   //called from inside a child HTML
    document.getElementById("titleText").innerHTML = title;
};
```

**child code:**

```
window.onload = function passTitle(){
    var title = $(document).find("title").text();
    parent.pageTitle(title);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `window.frames` - this is a list of frame objects (not an array - important to know for the second solution)

Then, the simplest way is this

```
var pageTitles = [];
for (i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
    if( !!window.frames[i].document) { // only frames in same domain
        pageTitles.push(window.frames[i].document.title);
    }
}
```

Or, little more advanced, but in my opinion the nicer way

```
var pageTitles = [].filter.call(window.frames, function(frame) {
    return !!frame.document; // return only frames in same domain
}).map(function(frame) {
    return frame.document.title;
});
```

> actually you could use just `window` without the `.frames` - at least in firefox, because `window.frames === window` - however, I'd recommend using `window.frames` for clarity in code

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!  Will this work even if I only have one iframe displaying at a time with back/forward buttons cycling between them?  Only page1.html is loaded in the beginning

Comment: it gets what is loaded, javascript has no precognitive powers to know what will be loaded possibly at some time in the future ... if you want to pre-read ALL the possible iframe content for their title before they are actually iframes, that's NOT what you asked for, and the answer is a bit more complex in that case, but still doable